# Integrating Compass into Visual Studio 2013 update 2 with Web Essentials 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, compass-sass, web-essentials

The way I currently have it set up is I downloaded Compass from https://github.com/Compass/compass

Placed it into the root of where all my SCSS files are located. It works great but, I was wondering if their is a way to integrate Compass like they are doing with the Mindscape Workbench http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I use just the mixins from Compass, but rely on Web Essentials to compile the SCSS files on save.** This gives me a much better development experience, since `compass watch` requires a few seconds to compile the stylesheets, whereas the Web Essentials are very fast. With `compass watch` I often had the problem that I reloaded my page in the browser before the CSS files were completely compiled, confusing me at times.

Since the Compass SCSS files are effectively a library that I rely on, I also copied them into my source tree, so that I have them in the Git repo. This also solved the problem that the Web Essentials were unable to resolve the Compass files.

This approach works very well for me, much better than with Mindscape Workbench. I must say I'm not a big fan of Mindscape Workbench, although my experiments with it lie approximately one year back. But YMMV.

Comment: My biggest gripe with Mindscape Web Workbench is that it doesn't resolve the compass imports, leaving `Undeclared mixin` warnings littering the Error List. Sure, these warnings are inconsequential, but that's not a good reason to ignore them. I read somewhere else that using VS2013's builtin scss support with compass download didn't give you access to compass helper functions. Have you run into any issues with your approach almost 1 year later?

Comment: Some of the compass mixins (especially the CSS3) use SASS extensions, that if not installed, will throw errors when the new *Web Compiler* extension tries to compile the SCSS files. Have you found a way around taht?